# Weird one (checking last time a python file was executed)

Tags: python, terminal, applescript

Weird one. I have an applescript that calls a python file every time the laptop wakes from a sleep. The apple script opens the terminal and calls the python file. The python file has functions in it  that run certain code if it is a certain time of the day.  like this:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().hour
if 9 <= now <= 10 :
    then do python stuff...

now = datetime.datetime.now().hour
if 15<= now <= 18 :
    then do python stuff...

now = datetime.datetime.now().hour
if 22<= now <= 23 :
    then do python stuff...
```

So as you can see above there are certain times of the day that specific python functions will be executed. My problem is that i want to only run the python functions once within that timeframe. At the moment if the laptop wakes up twice within the time frames above then the python functions will be run twice.
Is there a way to solve this in the python file that i am calling?
I know there are probably many ways to attack this problem i.e applescripts, terminal commands or python files. to be honest i dont know where to start so i guessed id start with python and work backwards.

I am thinking if we could check when the python file was last executed and stopping it if it was evicted within the specified time frame already. Then this could be a way of stoping it running twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the time of the last execution to a file:

```
...
with open('path/to/file', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(now.timestamp()))
```

In the top of the script, attempt to read from said file:

```
try:
    with open('path/to/file') as f:
        last_execution_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(f.read()))
except FileNotFoundError:  # will happen in the first execution, obviously
        last_execution_time = now

# do whatever logic you want to perform with `last_execution_time` and `now`
...
```

Comment: Thanks for having a go. i can't seem to get it working right now but il have another go tomorrow morning thanks again. seem to be getting an error: AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'fromtimestamp'